# Skip a line if runtime exceeds certain time limit for a single code - VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

Im creating a form where all credentials are automatically populated by anyone who accesses it. However I am facing difficulties trying to get the user's email address.

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

UserEmail = olNS.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
```

This one line could be taking >1 minute of some user's PC and few seconds on other's. 
Is there a way to skip this if its taking more than 5 seconds for example?

I'm thinking of applying application.ontime but dont know how to go from there.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not trivial. Usually, all your VBA code runs in a single thread. That means whenever any function gets stuck for a while, your whole code execution halts. [This question is about asynchronous calls in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574884/excel-vba-make-a-script-asynchronous) and basically says: It's not possible. So you would either need to find a way to modify the function that returns the email address to return early. Or launch a second VBA host and have it retrieve the address for you. If it does not provide it in time, continue without it.

Comment: Hey good idea to launch second vba host. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is not designed for running multithreaded calls. If you want to optimize performance of your Outlook VBA solutions you may consider creating a COM add-in instead. See [Chapter 12: Migrating VBA Solutions to VSTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627738(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Before accessing the address entry object I'd suggest getting the [Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/recipient-address-property-outlook) property value. It returns a string representing the e-mail address of the Recipient. If it corresponds to an SMTP address then you may skip unnecessary calls.